# Get a Ref to BlockListBlock in the block editor

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In gutenberg editor I need to get a ref to the BlockListBlock element but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to achieve this ?

```js
const withCustomAttribute = createHigherOrderComponent(
  (BlockListBlock) => {
    return (props) => {
      const blockRef = createRef();

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(blockRef); // => "{current: null}"
      });
      return <BlockListBlock {...props} ref={blockRef} />;
    };
  },
  'withCustomAttribute'
);

addFilter(
  'editor.BlockListBlock',
  'example/custom-attribute',
  withCustomAttribute
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is an easy way to achieve what you want, because `<BlockListBlock />` does not support any kind of `ref` passing.

You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/69e348ec80dc2cb9d537a8ba3cf6774b48636461/packages/block-editor/src/components/block-list/block.js#L71).

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use `useRef` instead, `createRef` won't save the value between re-renders.
2. You can't track it on the `useEffect`. Since it's not a react state, react won't trigger when it's changed. Instead, you can add wrap your console.log inside a setTimeout.

Something like this should give you the result you'd like:

```
      const blockRef = useRef();
      useEffect(() => {
         setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(blockRef); // => "{current: null}"
         }, 100)
      });
      return <BlockListBlock {...props} ref={blockRef} />;
```